# stacking images on top of paragraph columns

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to work with html and css to get a 3-column layout where I have a picture and then below that I have the paragraph text. [image: here is an image of how my columns look now. My second image is stuck in the first column and they are not stacking properly.]

**HTML**:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en"><head>
<meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
<meta charset="utf-8">

<title>Responsive Design Example by Alex Fogarty</title>


<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1">


<link href="figureCSS/reset.css" rel="stylesheet">

<link href="figureCSS/phone-default.css" rel="stylesheet">

<link href="figureCSS/tablet.css" rel="stylesheet">

<link href="figureCSS/desktop.css" rel="stylesheet">

<link href="about.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<link href="contact.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<link href="msum.css" rel="stylesheet"/>


</head>
<body>
<header>

 <a href="about.html">About</a> 
<br>

Contact

<br>

MSUM

</header>

<div id="content">


<figure class="stayssame">
 <video controls loop poster="placeholder.png" autoplay>
  <source src="video.mp4" type="video/mp4">
 <!-- <source src="movie.ogg" type="video/ogg">-->
Your browser does not support the video tag.
</video>
</figure>
<object type="image/svg+xml" data="newsvg.svg" ></object>

<div class="video-txt" ></div>


<section class="clearfix container" >
<h1>Kittens</h1>
<div>
<h2> Kitten One</h2>
<img class="img" src="kit1.jpg" alt="kitten one"/>
<p class="column-left">It is a long established fact that a reader will be distracted by the readable content of a page when looking at its layout. The point of using Lorem Ipsum is that it has a more-or-less normal distribution of letters, as opposed to using 'Content here, content here', making it look like readable English. Many desktop publishing packages and web page editors now use Lorem Ipsum as their default model text, and a search for 'lorem ipsum' will uncover many web sites still in their infancy. Various versions have evolved over the years, sometimes by accident, sometimes on purpose (injected humour and the like).</p>
<h2>Kitten Two</h2>
<img class="img" src="kit2.jpg" alt="kitten two"/>
    <p class="column-center">It is a long established fact that a reader will be distracted by the readable content of a page when looking at its layout. The point of using Lorem Ipsum is that it has a more-or-less normal distribution of letters, as opposed to using 'Content here, content here', making it look like readable English. Many desktop publishing packages and web page editors now use Lorem Ipsum as their default model text, and a search for 'lorem ipsum' will uncover many web sites still in their infancy. Various versions have evolved over the years, sometimes by accident, sometimes on purpose (injected humour and the like).</p>

<br>
<h2> Kitten Three</h2> 
     <br>
     <img class="img" src="kit33.jpg" alt="kitten three"/>
    <br>
        <p class="column-right">It is a long established fact that a reader will be distracted by the readable content of a page when looking at its layout. The point of using Lorem Ipsum is that it has a more-or-less normal distribution of letters, as opposed to using 'Content here, content here', making it look like readable English. Many desktop publishing packages and web page editors now use Lorem Ipsum as their default model text, and a search for 'lorem ipsum' will uncover many web sites still in their infancy. Various versions have evolved over the years, sometimes by accident, sometimes on purpose (injected humour and the like).</p>

</div>
</section>



</div><!-- end of the row-->




</body></html>
```

**CSS**:

```
@media only screen and (min-width: 961px) {

header {
position: fixed;
z-index: 1000;
width: 100%;
top: 0px;
background-color:#FC0509;
}

/*-----CONTENT -----*/
figure.adjustable {
    width: 29%; 
}


.column-left{ float: left; width: 33%;

 }
.column-right{ float: right; width: 33%; 

}
.column-center{ display: inline-block; width: 33%;

 }

.container{
-webkit-column-count: 3; /* Chrome, Safari, Opera */
-moz-column-count: 3; /* Firefox */
 column-count: 3;
-webkit-column-gap: 40px; /* Chrome, Safari, Opera */
-moz-column-gap: 40px; /* Firefox */
column-gap: 40px;
-webkit-column-rule-style: solid; /* Chrome, Safari, Opera */
-moz-column-rule-style: solid; /* Firefox */
column-rule-style: solid;
-webkit-column-rule-width: 33%; /* Chrome, Safari, Opera */
-moz-column-rule-width: 33%; /* Firefox */
column-rule-width: 33%;


}

h1{

 -webkit-column-span: all; /* Chrome, Safari, Opera */
  column-span: all;
}

.clearfix:after {
content:" ";
display:block;
clear:both;
}
.img{

 position:relative;

 height: 200px; width: 300px; overflow: hidden

}



}
```

Any help on this would be very much appreciated! I'm new at this so don't judge too harshly.

Comment: You can have <img> within a <p>... Remove the position relative.

Comment: Also, when the code chunks in the examples get quite large, its often easier for us if you use codepen or jsfiddle etc.

Comment: okay I will try and use that in the future. However do you know how I would get my pictures to be above my paragraphs? @ZBerg

Answer (score 0):

It looks like what you've done is align the paragraphs with float, and not the images. What would be better would be to produce three columns that each contain a paragraph and an image. Like so.

**HTML**

```
<div class='cols'>
    <img src='yourimage.jpg' alt='Your Image'>
    <p>Your Text</p>
</div>
<div class='cols'>
    <img src='yourimage.jpg' alt='Your Image'>
    <p>Your Text</p>
</div>
<div class='cols'>
    <img src='yourimage.jpg' alt='Your Image'>
    <p>Your Text</p>
</div>
<div class='cl'></div>
```

**CSS**

```
.cols { float:left; width:33%; }
.cl   { clear:both; }
```

What this has done is produce three containers, one for each column. The 'cl' div is there to end that row effectivly.

Answer (score 0):

The best way to solve the problem would be to create three separate divs, each with a `width: 33%`, and `float: left;` rather than using a section with `column-count`. You might prefer a width of 30%, with 1% padding on each column. Note that it's important to give the images `max-width: 100%`, to ensure that they never become wider than the columns themselves!

I've created an example to illustrate this here: https://jsfiddle.net/105txexh/1/

I've also tidied up your code, and removed all code that is no longer necessary.

Hope this helps!